# Magento: Different products in the different store views under the same store?

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I have multi website, multi stored Magento shop, and I have a need to make some products available in one store_view, but not available in the other, where both store_views are part of the same store and website.

All my products are configurable with simple products attached to them. Only way I could think of solving this is registering a new product attribute through which I control where each product goes. That works great for the catalog and lists of products, but I have huge problems with single product view and choosing the configurable product options.

I can't seem to find where in Magento core those option are generated, so I could override that and strict some options for each store view. Basically, I need to know where is this

[image]

generated. My last resort would be managing this through AJAX, but there is already a lot of AJAX code and calls in that page that it would be confusing.

Any help or tip would be very appreciated.

Comment: why can't you use the "visibility" attribute (which is "store view" scoped)? Or is it the options of the configurable product you need to modify between 1 view and another?

Comment: To clarify: You have product that is in a website that has multiple views. You want that product only to be visible in some of the views for that website?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And I can't use "visibility" because it's a bit more complicated than that.

For example, I have one configurable product A. His simple products A1, A2, A3 need to be visible in store_view_1 and, A1,A2,A4,A5 in the store_view_2. 

Either way I have to override some Magento core classes.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that the way above is not working because the attribute enable/disable product has impact at website level and not store or store view! 
So if you do like tomakun says the product will be disabled at the whole website and not just for the store view you choose first!

I have the same problem that I want to assign different products all to one website but to different stores.

So far I just found the solution above to change the visibility at store view level.

But I think this not the optimal solution. It should be possible to disable a product on store level!

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already available by default in Magento.
For **bulk enabling/disabling products** for a particular store view, do the following:

- Go to your **Catalog > Products**
- **Select a store view** above the product list.

*You are now viewing all products included in THIS store view.*

- Once you have the correct store view selected, **select the products you want to Enable or Disable** using the checkbox on the left.
- Now, **using the Actions dropdown menu** on top right of the product list, choose 'Change Status', select 'Disabled' or 'Enabled' and hit the *Submit* button.

Doing this will Enable or Disable the selected products from the selected store view (step 2). This is good for bulk actions but **you can also do the same for all products one by one**:

Open your product, select the relevant store view on top left of the page. Then in the General Tab, you have status: Enabled or Disabled. Choose the option that you want to apply for the current store view and hit Save.

That's it!

Comment: This could be the right answer, but not running for me, I noticed that the column website left me choose only main website, also in the single product configuration the Web site tab shows the checkbox only at website level.

Comment: Same here. You need to create a website to move products. T___T If you have a store view only, there's no option to move items to a specific store view. The only way is to make a separate root category. :(