# Products not showing up in "French" and "English" and cannot be added in Manage Categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

when I change the view to English or French store view, there is no product in that category. Why aren't they inherit from All Store Views? how can I fix it?

Products added to the category while scope was "all store views". so it really should be in both French and English store now.

I did full re-index many times. I cleared the cache too.

see the bug in action [youtube]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE4h6H6PW78&feature=youtu.be

In "English" and "French" store views, new products not even show up when tried to add them again. They only can be added in "All Store Views" scope.

Magento version 1.6.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get that working by disabling all products and reenable for store views added after products were added.
To disable and reenable products for specific view, follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790279/magento-different-products-in-the-different-store-vews-under-the-same-store#8163367)

EDIT: before disable and enable your products back, I suggest to try reindexing and refreshing cache, from the System menu.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( I have multiple store views in subdirectories and non of the products show. (enabled, visibility, category, stock-status, inventory, etc.etc all correctly setup)

Answer (score 3):

Login to your magento admin panel

1. Go to System>>Index Management
2. Select All
3. Set Action to Reindex data
4. Click Submit
5. Go to System>>Cache Management
6. Select All
7. Set Action to Refresh
8. Click Submit

Now All product will be display at frontend

Comment: I have 4 store and single website, how can i display all products into store 1, for inventory I have created 4 stores, now i need to display all products into store 1, and also all store products available as it is appropriate stores.